# how to make json object send in below format

Tags: android, json, post

i am new in android and i dont know how to data post in json.

```
          {
            "LeadId": 1,
                "CompanyId": 2,
                "Name": "sample string 3",
                "CreatedBy": "1",
                "IsAgreementGenerated": true,
                "CustomerDc": {
                    "CustomerId": 1,
                    "AccountNo": "sample string 2",
                    "FirstName": "sample string 3",
                    "MiddleName": "sample string 4",
                    "LastName": "sample string 5",
                    "CompanyName": "sample string 6",
                    "CustomerTypeId": 7,
                    "ContactTypeId": 8,
                    "SourceId": 10,
                    "PrimaryEmail": "sample string 11",
                    "PrimaryPhone": "sample string 13",
                    "Address1": "sample string 22",
                    "CountryId": 24,
                    "StateId": 25,
                    "CityId": 26,
                    "Zipcode": "sample string 27",
                    "CompanyId": 30,
                    "IsActive": true,
                    "IsPrimaryBillingAddress": true,
                    "CreatedBy": true,
                    "CreatedDate": "2015-12-07T12:51:51.2792695+05:30"
        }
        }
```

this is my json data how can this format into json object. i want to somting like that

```
        JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
        object.put("LeadId", "1");
        object.put("CompanyId", "2");
        object.put("Name", "abhishek");
        object.put("CreatedBy", "1");
        object.put("IsAgreementGenerated", "true");
```

and now what ca i do for next step inside object.

Comment: Create another JSONObject with different name like `CustomerDcJSONObject` in same way as creating `object` and add it in `object` like `object.put("CustomerDc", CustomerDcJSONObject);`

Comment: sorry i don't understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create customerdc jsonobject and put to object.

```
JSONObject customerDcObject = new JSONObject();
            customerDcObject.put("CustomerId", "1");
            customerDcObject.put("AccountNo", "2");
            customerDcObject.put("FirstName", "abhishek");...//add other parameter
object.put("CustomerDc", customerDcObject);
```